# Easy to use web API's to start playing with

Tags: java, python, api

Im at the point where i would like to start playing around with some web information apis in my programs. Noting Specific but something that i can use with java or python. I tried using the google task api, but it seemed a little tough with the authentication process.Any suggestions?

Comment: What concepts do you know about? What do you want to learn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api) and the [Flickr API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/).  They're both pretty easy to work with: it's just a matter of constructing a URL, making a web request, getting the XML response and parsing that XML response.  They both have methods which are public and don't need authentication.

When you are a bit more comfortable, you can start looking at using authentication for user-specific data requests.  For OAuth with Java, you can have a look at the [OAuth-Signpost](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/) library.